# Why doesn't my jquery work on IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have this site: http://telya.wee.co.il that has some jquery affects on the main page.

All works fine on FF, chrome, IE8 but it looks horrible and doesn't work on IE7.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the surplus comma (,) from the

```
 $('#imagesFade').cycle({ 
     fx:     'scrollRight', 
     speed:  200, 
     timeout: 3000, 
     next:   '#next', 
     prev:   '#prev' , /* <-- this comma should be removed */
 });
```

when i removed and re-run the code edited the slideshow worked just fine (*and whatever follows should, as well*)

Answer (score 2):

First thing that catches my eye is the extra comma after '#prev':

```
$('#imagesFade').cycle({ 
  fx:     'scrollRight', 
  speed:  200, 
  timeout: 3000, 
  next:   '#next', 
  prev:   '#prev' ,
});
```

IEs are picky about those.